# Error : onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in this activity

Tags: java, android

Being new to Android Application development i was trying to learn connecting two activities using Intent. I tried a code from a book. It keeps throwing an error saying - 'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in MainActivity class as well as the NewActivity class. Would be of great help if i could get a solution.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
            }
        });

    }
```

NewActivity.class

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    }
}
```

Comment: why you have it twice ?

Comment: To connect two activities you just need to put inside ` protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` this intent :  
`Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
startActivity(i);`

Comment: @Blackbelt : I was learning about how to do it and i came across this code in a book.

Comment: You have two onCreate methods, this is totally wrong... Take a look at this  simpe example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/

Comment: @JoanColmenero : How do i add both into a single onCreate(Bundle) function ?

Comment: @Blackbelt : One is for the MainActivity's layout and the other one is for the NewActivity's layout so thought that is why we have twice. How do i do it inside a single function ?

Comment: you need a huge introduction to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect those activities you have to do this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

And then in yout second activity just delete the:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
}
```

And copy this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
}
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your **NewActivity** to:

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    }
}
```

A class can contain only one onCreate() method.First learn about Activity Life Cycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first onCreate event on your main activity and new activity. you don't need twice

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
/*protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}*/

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, here are some examples of simple codes that might be useful in getting started with app development:

1. **Create a new activity:**

```java
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    }
}
```

2. **Open a new activity on click of a button:**

```java
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

3. **Display alert message:**

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("عنوان الرسالة")
       .setMessage("نص الرسالة")
       .setPositiveButton("موافق", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // إغلاق الرسالة
           }
       })
       .show();
```

4. **Use SharedPreferences To store data:**

```java
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.apply();
```

5. **Read data from SharedPreferences:**

```java
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = preferences.getString("key", "default_value");
```